# Is the "antenna aperture" the same as the "hole in the shield"?

Tags: rf, antenna, electromagnetism, basic, shielding

Is the concept of the ["Antenna Aperture"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_aperture) the same as a hole in a electromagnetic shield? The wikipedia article is quite vague, and I am a newbie in this field.

For example if we have an electric device and we put it in a steel box, that has sufficient depth. But the steel box has 1 piece of 1 cm hole in it. That should block any signal up to 29.979 GHz, since the maximum wavelength that can leak out from that hole is 1 cm.

Is this the same concept as the "Antenna Aperture", if not then what is the relationship?

Answer (score 1):

Antenna Aperture refers to the area of radio waves that is equivalent to the power that is obtained from a given antenna. This is always smaller than the physical size of the antenna since no antenna can extract all of the RF power that passes through it. It does not refer to physical aperture but is called that due to the similarity to the aperture of a camera, the larger the aperture the more power is received from a given intensity of radio waves/light and in both is basically a measure of the efficiency/sensitivity.

However a generalisation of the concept could be applied to what you are talking about, you could create a similar metric for the amount of power that passes through an aperture of a given size in terms of an area of the source field. That would give you an "effective aperture" which would be useful in calculating the power that will leak in but except for very simple apertures it is something you would need to measure to have a accurate result. Though when you are designing RF shielding you do not normally use anything like the accuracy used in designing antennas, since it is not very hard or costly to make something much more effective than is needed.

I googled some pages that might help, I only just skimmed them though to see if they looked useful:
http://incompliancemag.com/article/the-basic-principles-of-shielding/
http://www.compliance-club.com/archive/keitharmstrong/design_techniques4.html
https://interferencetechnology.com/analysis-shielding-effectiveness-board-level-shielding-apertures/

Even if it's not a problem you might as well just stick some aluminium tape on it if you have some lying around.

Comment: to be clear about TWiz is saying: **antenna aperture** is the maximum power (measured in watts) delivered by an antenna to a correctly matched load impedance divided by the RF intensity (measured in watts per sq. meter).  so you can think of that antenna sorta as scooping up some energy outa the air (or space) and the aperture is a measure of how big the mouth of the scoop is.  and i think for microwaves and these big structures you used to see on those towers the phone company had, that the aperture *was* approximately as big as the operative face of the structure.

Answer (score 1):

Can mean different things.  Aperture like a speaker hole in a bass reflex design  for woofer bass can be 10m wavelength  but a small fraction hole size still lets out energy.  Although reasons of cabinet resonance and dampening air flow it still escapes out the fractional wavelength of the hole size.

For this reason the grid size in microwave screen doors and Lingren walk-in Faraday cages are sized as small as necessary to achieve high attenuation and tuning holes for 3m high power transmitters use something like a <5mm hole.

However if we want a resonant antenna at 1/4 or 1/2 wavelength to emit with many elements to get more focus or a narrower beam angle, this achieves some gain like a parabolic mirror for flashlight then we consider the aperture of the half power angle of the beam at a certain distance rather than the stray radiation 100 db down (or whatever) for shielding purposes.

It is this beam spreading or focus aperture that you read about in Wiki.

Keep in mind a small pin hole still lets out light but not efficiently, unless the emitter is tiny and directly under the hole. Like a 1mm chip inside a 5mm LED directly under a thin 1mm hole.

Answer (score 0):

### The word "aperture" has more than one meaning.

One meaning is a physical hole or opening cut into some material such as a shield. And it appears that **you are confusing that definition with antenna aperture**, which are two totally different concepts.

***In this context, the effective aperture of an antenna system is directly related to its gain.***

Keep in mind that effective aperture is neither directly related to the actual size of an antenna (the possible exception being a parabolic dish) nor to the thickness of its elements.

Having said this, antennas DO exist consisting of a flat sheet with a slot in it, and the actual radiation comes from that hole ("aperture"). The one I'm thinking of has balanced feedline connected in the center of a rectangular slot.

**As for shielding,** holes are permissible as long their size does not exceed a certain relationship to the wavelength. (Google *shield holes cutoff frequency*.)
https://leadertechinc.com/blog/how-apertures-affect-emi-shielding/